# Use of quotations

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to quote a line that you would have said if somebody had told you something?

For example:

> If someone had foretold that I would hold you so close to my heart, I would have laughed and said, **"No way, that is totally unlikely."**

Or should it be:

> If someone had foretold that I would hold you so close to my heart, I would have laughed and said, **no way, that is totally unlikely.**

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *quotation* (even, as in this case, one that is hypothetical), and not something that's being described as *actually* spoken (dialogue), *and* if it's syntactically part of the introductory text, then you don't need a comma—but you do need quotation marks.

In other words:

> If someone had foretold that I would hold you so close to my heart, I would have laughed and said "no way, that is totally unlikely."

Note that "no" is in lowercase because it's not being punctuated as actual speech, but flows as part of the sentence itself.

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed), 13.15:

> Many writers mistakenly use a comma to introduce any direct quotation, regardless of its relationship to the surrounding text. But when a quotation introduced midsentence forms a syntactical part of the surrounding sentence, no comma or other mark of punctuation is needed to introduce it, though punctuation may be required for other reasons.
>
> Donovan made a slight bow and said he was “very glad.”
>
> One of the protesters scrawled “Long live opera!” in huge red letters.
>
> According to one critic, Copland’s style could be called “American urban pastoral, with a touch of jazz and more than a hint of Stravinsky.”

In the second example, it *does* start with a capital letter because that's the only way to make sense of the exclamation point that terminates the quotation. But note that the exclamation point inside the quotation marks does not actually terminate the sentence that it's part of. (Aside from an exclamation point, only a question mark would cause a similar effect.)

Comment: In this case, I prefer the version with the comma and the capital letter. I don’t think the OPs example sentence falls under the category of “a syntactical part of the surrounding sentence.” However, I’d use your guidance for the following: _...I would have laughed and said that is "totally unlikely.”_ The three examples you quote all have a verb (_was, scrawled, called_) right before the quoted text that seems to set it apart differently from the OPs example – though it might be a judgment call.

Comment: @J.R. I partially agree with you— because of the **said** dialogue "tag" immediately preceding it, something we commonly associate with normal comma-introduced dialogue. So, while I paused before saying anything, I'm not sure if it's just an emotional objection or actually an intellectual one. That it's hypothetical, and not an actual account, seems to lend itself more to a one-off quotation in my mind. But you're certainly right about using a capital letter if you *do* use a comma. (I should note that **said** is also a verb, so I don't think that can be a sufficient criterion.)

Answer (score 0):

I think any answer to this question may be open to debate, because in creative writing you *can be creative*, within reason.

You are asking **how to quote something that was never actually said**. I don't feel that anyone can be dogmatic and insist that you *must* still quote.

As a rule, you **only** use quotation marks when a quote is **perfect**; that is it is *exactly as spoken*.

**But!** You *can* quote a *thought*.

**Example:**

> "No way," I thought, "that is totally unlikely."

So something doesn't have to be *spoken* to be *quoted*. Arguably then you could still quote something you *thought* about saying but did not actually vocalise.

However, in your example you are *not* speaking about something you thought, but stating what you believe you *would* say if a certain circumstance arose. Also, your extract is written in the first person, which means *you* are speaking for the entire sentence. Adding quotes may seem a little jarring because it will seem like a division between your narrative and speech which isn't actually there. To me, the words you would have said seem like part of your narrative. Personally, I would use *italics* instead:

> If someone had foretold that I would hold you so close to my heart, I would have laughed and said *no way, that is totally unlikely*.

Others may disagree, but as your words are neither a *perfect quotation* of something said, nor an *internal monologue*, or thought that you *had*, I feel this would be an acceptable alternative.